# How to fix java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to compile the following gradle dependency

```
compile 'com.pandaos:bambooplayer:0.0.7'
```

but I'm facing ZipExceptions while building projects. The first exception was

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzkh.class
```

and I managed to resolve it as follows

```
compile ('com.pandaos:bambooplayer:0.0.7'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

This fixed the gms exception but now I'm faced with

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class
```

I've tried resolving it by modifying my compile statement as

```
compile ('com.pandaos:bambooplayer:0.0.7'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    exclude group: 'com.android.vending.billing'
}
```

But the error remains the same. Is this the correct way to exclude multiple dependencies from a single compile statement or am I doing something wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.